# how to send byte array's over bluetooth on android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, bluetooth, byte

I am trying to send a byte array over bluetooth on android. I have a server/client setup working. I send log in details such as strings and integers from one to the other (working both ways). Now I come to a bit in my program where I am required to send multiple byte arrays across. My server first sends an integer corresponding to the length of the array and then the byte[]. The client mirrors this with reading an int, and reading an array. The first int sends over correctly but after that the client is reading huge values of ints which the server doesn't seem to be sending.

Here is my code for the server side:

```
case 25:
    Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "STARTING CODE 25");
    while (true) {

    ArrayList<byte[]> toSend = queue.take();
    Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "TAKEN IMAGES");
    Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "taken images size = " + toSend.size());

    for (int i = 0; i < toSend.size(); i++){
        Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "item length = " + toSend.get(i).length);
        oos.writeInt(toSend.get(i).length);
        oos.flush();
        oos.reset();

        oos.write(toSend.get(i));
        oos.flush();
        oos.reset();
    }

    Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "SENT IMAGES");
    Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "SENT images size = " + toSend.size());
}
```

Here are the logs from the server side:

[image: server log]

Here is the client code:

```
case 25:
            while (true){
                Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "WAITING FOR IMAGES");

                ArrayList<byte[]> received = new ArrayList<byte[]>();

                for (int i = 0; i <25; i++){
                    int size = ois.readInt();
                    Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "BYTE ARRAY SIZE: " + size);
                    byte[] item = new byte[size];
                    ois.read(item);
                    received.add(item);
                }

                Message message = handler.obtainMessage(BITMAP,
                        received);
                Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "READ IMAGES");
                Log.d("CONSEQUENCES", "images size = " + received.size());
                handler.sendMessage(message);
            }
```

and the client logs:

[image: client log]

Any ideas why I am receiving such big ints or why it is failing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was getting these ints because the whole of the byte array was not being sent over. I replaced:

```
ois.read(item);
```

with

```
int readBytes = -1;
while (readBytes != size)  {
    readBytes = readBytes + ois.read(item,readBytes,size-readBytes);
}
```